# SELECT in FIREBASE does not return anything

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the value of the table SFPTB032_ABERTURAESP with:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM SFPTB032_ABERTURAESP;
```

But nothing happens. I've already try to find a solution, but nothing is really working.

Table description:

```
MM_COMPETENCIA                  SMALLINT Not Null 
AA_COMPETENCIA                  SMALLINT Not Null 
DT_RECOLHIMENTO                 TIMESTAMP Not Null 
IC_DISCO_GERADO                 (D_SIM_NAO) CHAR(1) Not Null  default 'N'
                                check (VALUE is null or ( VALUE in ('S','N') ))
IC_SITUACAO_FINANCEIRA          (D_IND_SIT_FINANCEIRO) CHAR(1) Nullable 
                                check (VALUE is null or ( VALUE in ('A','F','S') ))
CO_RECOLHIMENTO                 CHAR(3) Not Null 
IC_RECOLHIMENTO_FGTS            SMALLINT Nullable
```

The "dabatase" field isn't my area of expertise, so a help would be very good here.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site for the database that you are using. I'm pretty sure it isn't Firebase, but I can't figure out what it *is*.

Comment: Yep, what Puf said. Firebase isn't a SQL database.

Comment: If the select doesn't return anything, then obviously there are no rows in that table. Did you insert anything in there? What does `SELECT count(*) FROM SFPTB032_ABERTURAESP;` return?